# Restarting a systemd service upon a network 'up' event

Tags: networking, systemd, users

My system requires the use of a vpn, of which I use `expressvpn` which is based upon OpenVpn but uses its own `systemd` daemon. All connect/disconnect commands must go through the provided binary. In order to not type these commands into the terminal after every reboot or wake from sleep (and to configure a few iptable rules) I have placed a script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` catching the 'up' event.

While the script works, I am experiencing problems with `expressvpn connect`. After waking from sleep it acts as though multiple connect commands have been invoked. A simple solution is to restart its service.

I can issue a `systemctl restart expressvpn` followed by a `expressvpn connect` command from the terminal (as both user and sudo) without any problems, but if I add the restart command to the dispatcher script something breaks.

This is the problematic part of the script (including my temp logger lines):

```
date "+%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%y" &> /home/twifty/Desktop/up-log.txt

echo "restarting..." >> /home/twifty/Desktop/up-log.txt

#systemctl stop expressvpn >> /home/twifty/Desktop/up-log.txt
#systemctl start expressvpn >> /home/twifty/Desktop/up-log.txt
systemctl restart expressvpn.service

echo "connecting..." >> /home/twifty/Desktop/up-log.txt

#/usr/bin/expressvpn status >> /home/twifty/Desktop/up-log.txt
/usr/bin/expressvpn disconnect >> /home/twifty/Desktop/up-log.txt
/usr/bin/expressvpn connect >> /home/twifty/Desktop/up-log.txt

echo "setup..." >> /home/twifty/Desktop/up-log.txt
```

The `expressvpn disconnect` and `connect` command should output its sucess or failure, but nothing is written to the file.

The service status `systemctl status expressvpn` after running the script looks like:

```
● expressvpn.service - ExpressVPN Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/expressvpn.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-08-21 11:53:20 CST; 16s ago
 Main PID: 5043 (expressvpnd)
    Tasks: 10 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/expressvpn.service
           └─5043 /usr/sbin/expressvpnd --client-version 1.2.0 --client-build 167

Aug 21 11:53:20 twifty-lynx systemd[1]: Started ExpressVPN Daemon.
Aug 21 11:53:20 twifty-lynx expressvpnd[5043]: /sbin/resolvconf: illegal option -- -
Aug 21 11:53:20 twifty-lynx expressvpnd[5043]: /sbin/resolvconf: illegal option -- e
Aug 21 11:53:20 twifty-lynx expressvpnd[5043]: /sbin/resolvconf: illegal option -- n
Aug 21 11:53:20 twifty-lynx expressvpnd[5043]: event_dispather: invalid subscriber addr or protocol2017/08/21 11:53:20 method Authenticate 
Aug 21 11:53:20 twifty-lynx expressvpnd[5043]: 2017/08/21 11:53:20 method SetAuth has wrong number of ins: 2
Aug 21 11:53:20 twifty-lynx expressvpnd[5043]: openvpn-expressvpn: no process found
```

whereas, running from the terminal, the output will contain:

```
Aug 21 13:12:09 twifty-lynx sudo[4673]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/dmidecode -s system-uuid
Aug 21 13:12:09 twifty-lynx sudo[4673]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 21 13:12:09 twifty-lynx sudo[4673]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

without the `systemctl restart` line, the script runs correctly, or if I run that command as myself `sudo -u twifty systemctl restart`, it will also succeed. I believe this is a bug within expressvpn itself (not supporting multiple simultaneous users).

I don't want to hard code my user name within the script, I also want to support remote as well as local access. How can I set this up to support multiple users?

Update:

Prefixing the commands with `sudo -u twifty` does not work. When waking from a long sleep, expressvpn still acts as though multiple connect commands have been invoked, as evident by there being two `tunX` interfaces created when there should only be a single `tun0`. This is exactly the same behaviour I noticed before the reset the service fix.